# GROUP BY one column, then by another column

Tags: postgresql

[image]

```
SELECT lkey, max(votecount) FROM VOTES
WHERE ekey = (SELECT ekey FROM Elections where electionid='NR2019')
GROUP BY lkey
ORDER BY lkey ASC
```

Is there an easy way to get the pkey in this Statement?

Solution should look like this
[image]

Comment: group by lkey, pkey?

Comment: @SergeyMiryanov doens't work. Either grouped by lkey or pkey

Comment: You want to get pkey for maximum votecount value in lkey group? Because I'm not sure that I get what you want to achive - group by lkey, pkey do that you wrote in the title.

Comment: `max(votecount)` per `lkey` alone contains all `votecount`s for all `pkey`s, so the result of `group by lkey, pkey` will be the same as the table in the first screenshot, which I assume is the input table. @visCode it would help if you edited your question to better explain what you want to achieve. Your current expected result could be a plain `select lkey,pkey from subquery where (lkey=1 and pkey=2) or (lkey=2 and pkey=2)` for all we know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (v.ikey) v.*
FROM VOTES v
INNER JOIN Elections e ON e.ekey = v.ekey
WHERE e.electionid = 'NR2019'
ORDER BY v.ikey, v.votecount DESC;
```

In plain English, the above query says to return the single record for each `ikey` value having the highest vote count.